# data grip json groovy format integers to an unexpected format

Tags: json, datagrip

I have a column in number which contains 1000000000 and when I export it to json-Groovy with DataGrip it takes 1.0E9 as value ( scientific format), is there a way to let it as it was?

Comment: What database do you use? What is the type of the field?

Comment: I use a mysql database with a double type